# MarkLogic andQuery

Tags: marklogic

I am learning MarkLogic and I have to query the most profitable companies in Pennsylvania with between 4000 and 10000 employees. I am new to this and am trying to figure out how to use the andQuery. Here is what I have the runs:
'use strict';

```
const jSearch = require('/MarkLogic/jsearch'); 

if (xdmp.databaseName(xdmp.database()) === 'data-hub-STAGING') {
const companies = jSearch.collections('company');

companies.documents()
.where(
jSearch.byExample([
{"$and": [
{ "EMPLOYEES": { "$le": 10000 } },
{ "EMPLOYEES": { "$ge": 4000 } }]
}
])
)
.orderBy(cts.indexOrder(cts.jsonPropertyReference('PROFIT')), 'descending')
.slice(0,5)
.result(); 

} else {
'Please select the data-hub-STAGING database and run this code again.';
}
```

Am I able to add another search option like {'STATE': {'PA'}}, or do I need to write a second query to use andQuery joining them?

Answer (score 0):

Your `$and` already has multiple constraints. It takes an array, so yes, you can just append to that array.

HTH!